# Photoshop doesn't recognize image when I export; keeps trying to export blank background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, background, jpg

Note: This is happening on all PSD files that I have.

I'm trying to export a couple of images from an artboard I made in Photoshop. But it's not recognizing the images. Instead it keeps trying to export a blank background instead:

[image]

Layers on the side: no transparent background as you can see.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you perhaps upload the file somewhere or add a screenshot of how your main window (showing the layers panel, etc...) looks?

Comment: [Here's](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9618004#9618004) a link to someone with the same problem. Time to call Adobe perhaps? Tech support questions are off topic here.